# Android Tab Turn Back to ActivityGroup

Tags: android, tabs, activitygroup

I'm using ActivityGroup for my tabs.

In my TabActivity onCreate

```
tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;
    Intent intent;

    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");
    tabSpec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```

And my FirstActivity extends ActivityGroup and after a button click I'm going to SecondActivity like that;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("xyz", intent).getDecorView();
                    setContentView(view);
```

And when I'm in the SecondActivity, after click the "tab1", I can not go to FirstActivity. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to start first activity by activity group like this

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this,FirstActivity.class);
    startChildActivity("first", intent);
```

then create FirstActivity as simple activity and then start second activity.

And also try this link

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Comment: Is there a method called startChildActivity? I couldn't find which class has this method. Secondly, my FirstActivity class is ActivityGroup. I can not understand your suggestion, you mention about not using ActivityGroup?

Comment: startChildActivity is a method to start a child activity. and did u use TabGroupActivity class?